# How to skip a cell in MS Excel IF function when the condition is false

Tags: excel

Suppose I have values in cell

```
A4, A8, A12,......A1600
```

Now, I am using an IF function to fill those empty cells in *Column A*.

For example, assume it to be,

```
=IF(NOT(MOD(ROW(),4) = 0), 1,)
```

Now, here I used a pretty simple task as example. (But this is not the scenario. I have complex tasks in my mind. I used the example for making it simple). Here, The problem will happen is, it will be

```
A1 - 1
A2 - 1
A3 - 1
A4 - FALSE
A5 - 1
............
............
A1599 - 1
A1600 - FALSE
```

But my goal is to keep those cells untouched. Such as, when, condition in IF is not met or more specifically IF is in false block, it'll simply skip that cell and check for the next cell. 
For demo, It'll print **A3 as 1**, but when it goes to **A4**, false condition is met, and it will do nothing in **A4**, and just skip that and go to **A5** for next task. What I want is it'll not touch A4 (assume that I have important values in those cells).
So that, after the formula is implemented it'll be like,

```
A1 - 1
A2 - 1
A3 - 1
A4 - Untouched and previous value (as skipped)
A5 - 1
............
............
A1599 - 1
A1600 - Untouched and previous value (as skipped)
```

Now, I've already read about *helper cell method*, or the *VBA method*. But, I really want to know is it possible in the excel functional space to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Pratyya10 if you add an empty string ( `""` ) to your formula after the last comma it should leave that cell "untouched".

`=IF(NOT(MOD(ROW(),4) = 0), 1,"")`

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I don't think that. Rather it'll add a blank space. If you had data in the 4th cell, you'd find out that it replaces that data with a blank space. Which means not "untouched"

Comment: @Pratyya10 entering a blank space is the closest thing to "untouched" that you will be able to get. what you are referring to is a circular reference, here's an article that talks about them. read it carefully because these are dangerous waters
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123